# Nginx epoll_wait() issue under load test with Load Balancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, load-testing, amazon-alb

I'm using JMeter CLI to load tests our micro services (Nginx+PHP-FPM+Laravel).

Micro services are all under an AWS Application Load Balancer which performs a health-check.

For that micro service, load test runs with an average of 50req/s. After few minutes, health check is failing with

```
50#50: *835 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, 
so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream,
client: **.**.**.**, server: _, request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "**.**.**.**:32807"
```

While the requests from JMeter are still ok.

It's the only micro service that gives the error. They all have the same nginx config though.

I'm really clueless.

Comment: This message means that the ALB health check disconnected from your server. Probably it timed out before receiving a response from your app. Time to scale out.